# scipy.sparse for numpy.random_multivariate_normal

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I wanted to save a bit of memory, and thought I'd create a `scipy.sparse` identity matrix (`dim` is in the thousands, not terrible, but also not frugal). Notice its shape passes the `assert`:

```
cov = sigma_0 * sparse.identity(dim, dtype=np.float32)
assert (dim, dim) == cov.shape
result = np.random.multivariate_normal(mu, cov)
```

> ```
> E   ValueError: cov must be 2 dimensional and square
> ```

The following, however, works fine:

```
cov = sigma_0 * np.identity(dim, dtype=np.float32)
assert (dim, dim) == cov.shape
result = np.random.multivariate_normal(mu, cov)
```

Did I miss it, somewhere, in the docs to say that sparse covariance matrices are expected fail with a `ValueError`?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't believe that `numpy` is aware of sparse matrices at all. In general, the sparse matrices implement many of the same functions as numpy arrays, but if those are getting passed off to C code, then I bet the numpy functions won't work. In general, you can expect most of the functions in `scipy.sparse` to work with sparse matrices.

Comment: `numpy` functions work with sparse matrices IF they delegate the action to the array's own methods.  Otherwise they naively try to turn the matrix into a numpy array, and get it wrong.  `cov.toarray()` is the correct way of turning a sparse matrix into a dense one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's happening here is that in [`np.random.multivariate_normal`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/3c977be0fc5d7d61e8e1d20d0a06c7865458d93c/numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.pyx#L4528) the input array is cast to an array:

```py
cov = np.array(cov)
```

which ends up creating a scalar array of dtype `object` since numpy doesn't know anything about sparse matrices.

```
In [3]: cov = sparse.identity(100, dtype=np.float32)

In [4]: cov.shape
Out[4]: (100, 100)

In [5]: np.array(cov)
Out[5]: 
array(<100x100 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float32'>'
        with 100 stored elements (1 diagonals) in DIAgonal format>, dtype=object)
```